# Trying to read JSON data in request in NodeJS

Tags: html, node.js, angular

I'm sending the below request from an angular app to my node backend. However, I cant seem to access the body of the request, instead just getting undefined being printed by the console. Where am I going wrong?

Request

[image: the request being sent]

Angular post request

```
logIn(email: string, password: string) {
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/login', { email: email, password: password });
}
```

NodeJS backend

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  let chunks = [];
  req.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
  req.on('end', () => {
    let data = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    let schema = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log('Data: ', schema.email);
  });

}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: I would be using express for this... but nevertheless: what happens, if you omit `JSON.stringify` and use the data as string directly?

Comment: @devnull69 if i get rid of the stringify and try to console log the schema variable i get undefined:1 as output and a syntax error 'Unexpected end of JSON input'

Comment: Are the `chunk` values buffers?

Comment: You should check the chunks content and possibly convert it to string before parsing it

Comment: @Quentin i console logged the chunk variable, the output was "{ type: 'Buffer', data: [] }"

Comment: @devnull69 the chunk content when I output them are in the above comment

Comment: `JSON.parse()` expects a string, not a buffer.  And, it makes no sense you're calling `JSON.stringify()`.  Try `let schema = JSON.parse(data.toString());`.  And, put a `try/catch` around it so you get notified of the precise error if there's an error.

Comment: @jfriend00 got 'Unexpected end of JSON input' as my output for that

Comment: @Oblivion - Then your JSON isn't valid and you need to examine what exactly the data is and debug from there - as it apparently is not legal JSON.  It seems you haven't described any simple debugging steps you've taken to analyze your problem.  You should be doing that yourself.